# Unwanted smoothing by gnuplottex in matrix plot

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I have a datafile containing some kind of phase data in matrix form. Plotting the data with standalone gnuplot via

```
plot 'gridB.dat' matrix w image
```

gives the following result:
[image: Right image]

Which is, up to some beautifying, how I want it to be. Then I try to directly integrate the plot into my Latex document via gnuplottex. A minimal `test.tex` file would be

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions={color size 14.5cm, 9cm}]
            unset key
            plot 'gridB.dat' matrix w image
        \end{gnuplot}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compilation is done via

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

The output is the following:
[image: Wrong picture]

It looks like some unwanted smoothing is applied. Any ideas why this happens and how I can avoid it?

I use TexLive-2012 and gnuplot 4.6 on OSX. The `gridB.dat` file is available [here](http://haatschii.de/gridB.dat).

Comment: For me your example works fine on Linux with gnuplot 4.6.5 and TeXLive 2012 (also with 2014). Please give us a *full* but minimal example which gives you the problems. Also make sure you delete intermediate files before retrying. I used `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{gnuplottex}\begin{document}\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex ...` for testing. Also describe how you compile. For me both `pdflatex -enable-write18 file.tex` and `latex -enable-write18 file.tex && dvips file.dvi && ps2pdf file.ps` works fine.

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks for your testing. I added a minimal example and my pdflatex call.

Comment: Ok, your example still works fine for me. Please check what your `file.log` says about the conversion from eps to pdf. Here I get `(epstopdf) Command: <epstopdf --outfile=grid2-gnuplottex-fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf grid2-gnuplottex-fig1.eps> ...`. Also, does it work if you don't use the `epstopdf` package, but the compile chain `latex && dvips && ps2pdf`?

Comment: @Christoph: My `.log` file contains the same line for epstopdf. I upgraded texLive to 2014 and also gnuplot, but it did not help. Looks like it is not the conversion from eps to pdf but the creation of the `.eps` file that breaks. At least the `.eps` file allready contains the shown smoothing... . Sorry I don't know how to use the `latex && dvips && ps2pdf` chain, can you explain?

Comment: Instead of using `pdflatex` you could run `latex --shell-escape file.tex` followed by `dvips file.dvi` and `ps2pdf file.ps`. This would skip the automatic conversion of the generated eps file to pdf, which I thought would be the culprit, because the `image` plotting style in gnuplot doesn't do any interpolation. How does the eps look like if you manually compile the `.gnuplot` file from gnuplottex? Maybe you have different gnuplot versions which are used depending if you compile manually or from inside latex? Add `set title sprintf('version = %.1f %s', GPVAL_VERSION, GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL)` to see.

Comment: @Christoph: Thx for explaining. Unfortunally the result is still the same. Also manually invoking gnuplot gives the same `.eps` file. The version printed is the same `version = 4.6 5`. Looks like my gnuplot is broken, isn't it? :(

Comment: That looks indeed quite strange, especially because you said that running a very minimal example from gnuplot directly works fine (I assume with the `wxt` terminal). Did you look at the `file-inc.eps` file when calling gnuplot manually? This is what gnuplot actually generates, the `file.eps` is what comes out after you already run latex one time.

Comment: @Christoph, sorry for the late update. It looks like it is not gnuplot but the OSX pdf/eps viewer. At least I created the `.eps` and `.pdf` files on a Debian system, where the look good, and copied them back to my system and the smothining occurt. So it is probably neither latexes nor gnuplots fault, instead probably Apple added a "feature" here... . Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by the pdf/eps viewer.